# How to set image in bottom right corner in container in flutter?

Tags: flutter

My first question is how to set image in bottom right corner, and the answer is

```
Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: (Image(image: AssetImage("images/bg_decore_up_la.png"),)),
            ),
```

It is working fine,
But in parent Scaffold I set

```
resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
```

means scroll is happening when keyboard is appear.
For this ,
This Align (image) widget i set out of SingleChildScrollView

Now my whole code like

```
Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true,
        appBar:AppBar(),
        body:SafeArea(
            child:Stack(
                children:[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: (Image(image: AssetImage("images/bg_decore_up_la.png"),)),
                  ),//want to fixed widget when keyboard will appear
                  ScrollConfiguration(
                      behavior: MyBehavior(),
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                         //scrolling widget list
                      )
                  )
                ]
            )
        )
    );
```

If i set

```
Align(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60),
            child: (
                Image(
                  image: AssetImage("images/bg_decore_bottom_la.png"),)),
          ),
```

this code fixed the issue,
but for this i need proper top margin

```
topMargin=totalScreenHeight-ImageWidth;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Stack and Positionned widget like so

```
Stack(
                children: const <Widget>[
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    right:0,
                    child: (Image(
                      image: AssetImage("images/bg_decore_up_la.png"),
                    )),
                  )
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: not working
image is still scroll when keyboard will apear